# Media control with terminal

Tags: command-line, xdotool, media-buttons

I've been trying to control my computer's media with terminal commands. The only way I've seen is to emulate a media key using xdotool, which is doesn't work when the screen locks. Is there a lower level or alternate option to control media even while the screen is locked through terminal?

Comment: Have you considered disabling screen locking?

Comment: I'd rather not, if that's the only option I'd rather just unlock it.

Answer (score 1):

If your media player supports [`MPRIS`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/), there are commandline tools available to send MPRIS commands over DBus to the player.

- [mpris-remote](http://incise.org/mpris-remote.html) (in the [universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/mpris-remote) in `trusty` and later)
- [playerctl](https://github.com/acrisci/playerctl)
- (others)

`MPRIS` runs over `D-Bus`, so you can also use tools like `qdbus` (from the `qdbus` package) to send direct queries.  See [Controlling Clementine with MPRIS](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/wiki/Controlling-Clementine-from-the-commandline-with-DBus-and-MPRIS) for examples.

Comment: note this does nothing to emulate media keys.  it goes directly to the root question of controlling the media player.